# Nullify file Through script not working

Tags: linux, unix, aix

`cp /dev/null log` working manually but from shell script it's not working for some logs.

Any idea why and how to fix this on AIX. Note: No ownership permission etc issue.

Comment: Then it's a PATH or working directory issue. Not much else to diagnose with, if you know what I mean. Oh, and did you forget to also tag this as Mac and Windows besides Linux and AIX? Which is it?

Comment: I tried to investigate it but no luck. Unfortunately it seems that no PATH or working directory issue as same setup in all machine and failing on few.

Comment: Error messages please, mate. No redirecting to /dev/null.

Comment: @Jens No error coming when running the script that's real issue as well. It's showing success but when listing files it's no nullified . On most of machine it's going good .Only one few machine having issue .

Comment: Are you perhaps running the script from cron?

Comment: Yes from cron but tried running manually having same issue for some specific log .

Answer (score 0):

There's important information missing. But what about simply using

```
: > log
```

to empty `log`? This doesn't need `cp` or `/dev/null` at all.

Comment: Even cat /dev/null > log not working for some logs in the machine.On same location it's working for most of the log but few logs giving issue.

Comment: How do you know *It's not working*? Maybe the log just gets filled quickly again after it became emptied. Who's writing the log? Is that writing process running while you truncate the log?

Comment: I am out of office right now. If you need some more info I can provide you but I think that is what I have .

Comment: Just to be more specific those are IHS serverisup and apps log.